# Cannot add unmovable type to unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, move-semantics, unordered-map

Please consider the following code:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <unordered_map>

struct S {
    std::mutex m;
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_map< int, S > u;

    u.emplace( 0, S() );
}
```

While the error message reported by gcc is unreadable, the gist of it is that because `std::mutex` is unmovable, I cannot create an element in the map of type `S`. Since the actual elements of the map never move, this is not a real problem. Indeed, the following program does compile:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <unordered_map>

struct S {
    std::mutex m;

    explicit S( int dummyArg ) {}
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_map< int, S > u;

    u.emplace( 0, 1 );
}
```

I am looking for a way to emplace an instance of `S` in the map without generating a dummy argument constructor.

Comment: It is a dupe, but one suggestion: rather than `int dummyArg`, do 
struct S {
    std::mutex m;
    S() {}
    struct default_construct_t {};
    static constexpr auto default_construct = default_construct_t();
    S(default_construct_t) : S() {}
};
```
so then you can do `u.emplace(0, S::default_construct);` which at least to me is clearer than `u.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::make_tuple(0), std::make_tuple());`